# Jquery works partly without events fires

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html file with a few js files and jquery.

Scripts from file 1.js work fine.
Scripts from file 2.js also work fine but Jquery don't works always. 
So I run some script and on result it should hide ".popup". Everything works – I run a message to console but events like hide() or click() don't work.

```
console.log("All done!");//works
console.log($(".popup"));//works fine – shows the right element in console

$(".popup").click();//doesn't work
$(".popup").hide();//doesn't work
```

I don't want to connect all scripts into one file and try to understand why there is always fine with scripts from one file and nothing works with another.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to specify click handler or if you want to do  click on that element   then you need to use trigger.. that is $(".popup").trigger("click");

Answer (score 1):

Since we can't see much of your code, my answer is only a good guess:

The reason is that your javascript is executed before the DOM is rendered, therefore `$(...)` which tries to select your element, just can't find it at this moment.

That's why jQuery has a `ready` function, which will be executed once your DOM is ready: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".popup").click();
      $(".popup").hide();
}
```

It works for your `console.log` statement because the value you pass to it is evaluated after the function is executed. (Actually i don't know the real reason for this, have to research myself)

Edit: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) explains the reason for the `console.log()` behaviour (chrome only)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help. But I have $(document).ready(function() { – and nothing works. It's not so simple :(

Comment: Could you provide some more code. Your basic markup (how do you include your scripts..) and the scripts itself would help us to find your problem